# Unable to start API 29 emulator (Android 10)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

As the title says, I have tried to create an Android 10 emulator, when trying to start the emulator nothing happens, only the phone appears on the screen but the device screen remains black, I do not get any error, I have waited but nothing ever happens. When I touch the close button I get "The emulator process for AVD Pixel_4_API_29 was killed"

I have tried deleting the image and downloading it again, installing the image on Pixel 1, 2, 3 and 4, run emulator with -writable-system, increase RAM, cold boot... unsuccessfully.

I have the rest of the emulators installed (from API 16 to API 30) working fine

The image I downloaded from Android Studio is located at "C:\Users\PCDELL\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-29\google_apis_playstore\x86"

**Upgrade**

I tried with:

API 29 x86_64 (Google Play)

API 29 x86 (Google APIs)

API 29 x86_64 (Google APIs)

API 29 x86_64 (Android Open Source Project)

The result is the same

Comment: Did you try pressing the power button on the side-bar or the device frame?

Comment: I tried it too, pressing and holding it but it doesn't work

Comment: Did you try deleting the device and again creating with one of the above images?

Comment: it seems a problem in last update 30.7.5 i have same problem and tried on 3 defferent devices and same problem

Comment: Yes, try everything mentioned above, deleting the device

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After many tests the only thing that worked for me was:

1. Uninstall Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager (HAXM) version v7.7.0
2. Enter https://github.com/intel/haxm/releases and download HAXM v7.4.1
3. Install HAXM v7.4.1

I suppose that a not so old version could work but I went to the extremes and downloaded the oldest one from the link

*I have the latest version of Android Studio (4.2.2) and also the latest version of the emulator (30.7.5)

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work for me. I still get the "The emulator process for AVD Pixel_4_API_29 was killed."

Comment: Thanks for this! In the end I installed the HAXM version that Android Studio recommends (7.6.5) and then it worked. I had 7.7.0 and the Android 10 emulator was indeed not working. I also tried 7.4.1 but my computer was crashing with a BSOD when opening the emulator. So at least 7.6.5 seems to be the one to use.

Comment: I just faced the same issue, only this solution worked for me after 4 days of testing every possible solution. I believe it is a BIOS update issue cause I did change my BIOS before.

Answer (score 2):

after multi tries i backed to version 30.7.4 and it worked fine
down it from this link

https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-windows_x64-7453540.zip

and extract it in sdk folder after deleting old emulator folder

**another workaround**

create text file and insert this two lines in it

```
Vulkan = off
GLDirectMem = on
```

save it in .android path like

> C:\Users\Sherif.android

don't forget to change the extension to **.ini**

[image]

Comment: After replacing the folder I get the message "No emulator installed" and it gives me the option to download version 30.7.5

Comment: I managed to replace the folder without errors but I still have the same problem, can you tell me the url to get more versions of the emulator?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not forced to use specifically Pixel 4 with API 30, then what worked for me was going down to Pixel2 API 30.
I know this is not much help if you are looking for a specific device but ...