# The emulator process for AVD XXX has terminated

Tags: android

I just installed Android Studio yesterday. I have all of the latest versions for the emulator, studio and adb.

I created a new emulator using Android Q API 29 arm64-v8a (Android 10). When trying to launch this I am getting `The emulator process for AVD Pixel 5 API 29 has terminated.`. I am not sure what the issue is. I have tried the following.

Adding `advancedFeatures.ini`
Making sure I have enough HDD space
Restarting
Making sure everything is up to date.

When launching from the terminal I get the error:

```
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator>emulator -avd Pixel_5_API_29
INFO    | Android emulator version 31.2.10.0 (build_id 8420304) (CL:N/A)
PANIC: Avd's CPU Architecture 'arm64' is not supported by the QEMU2 emulator on x86_64 host.
```

I am not sure what to do at this point. Not sure why Android Studio would offer these if the program cannot run it. I am on a Samsung S9+ and I am trying to develop using the same architecture.

Comment: try the solution in this topic
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68328469/11365488

Answer (score 0):

look at BobMorane's answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/71216466/19299549

```
#ifdef __x86_64__
    if (sarch == "arm64" && apiLevel >=28) {
        PAPANIC("Avd's CPU Architecture '%s' is not supported by the QEMU2 emulator on x86_64 host.\n", avdarch);
    }
#endiF
```